# Verifying User's current state in Authentication Flow

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

I'm working to create Authentication Flow but can't decide which way is better to go at

This Is How my flow goes:

```
Splash Screen
     ||
     \/
Sign Up with Email & Password (Using Firebase)
     ||
     \/
Fill Name, Phone, and Upload Profile Image
     ||
     \/
Waiting Page (Wait for Admin Approval)
     ||
     \/
Home Page
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this:
if the user signs up but didn't fill the Name/Phone/Image Section, When he logs back In again After a Reinstall or a sign out he will automatically be redirected to the Fill Name/Phone/Image Page,
if the user Filled the Info but is not Varified by the Admin send him to the waiting Page
if the user Filled and Info and also have been validated by the Admin send him to the Home page

Now I'm wavering between 2 option:

1. Using redux persist and saving the user state in the Auth
2. Using the Firebase Realtime database giving each user on signup an isFilled and isValid prop like so:

```
{
  "users": {
    "user1": {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      "isFilled": false,
      "isValid": false,

    },
    "user2": { ... },
    "user3": { ... }
  }
}
```

And then redirect accordingly

So my question is what way is better 1 or 2?
Or if there's a better way to achieve this I would love to hear it :)

Comment: do you want to check is that valid with the data you have on backend? or you want to check it is filled and valid for example as email?

Comment: whatever is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 would be preferred.

Its good that you have thought about locally caching the state in redux-persist but the problem would be user uninstalling and installing the app and losing the status of the user.

The other possibility is the user installing and creating the account from one phone and using another phone to login, So in this case you will have to access the firebase data to verify the state of the user.

And when the admin approved you can think of a firebase notification to notify the app, When the user opens the app you can redirect to home screen easily.

You can use redux-persist after the login and to store meta data which is will help the app load fast without relying on data from backend.

Comment: The problem with option 2 is that I need to check the current user in each page which seems not the best practice

Comment: True, you can maintain the current user in redux but then again if the user logs in using a different phone, you will have to think of managing scenarios like that. And as this is part of your user creation having an api call wont have a big impact